# Parceable Arraylist of objects

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList of Person Objects from the MainActivity to SecondActivity to print the details of the person in a custom listView adapter.

The application runs but it crashes when it reaches`startActivity()` to the SecondActivity after passing the ArrayList of Persons.

Person implements `Parcelable`

```
public Person(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Person(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(id);
    out.writeString(name);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Person> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Person>() 
{
    @Override
    public Person createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Person(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Person[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Person[size];
 }};
```

MainActivity

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

public void onButtonClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("personObject", list);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

SecondClass Activity

```
protected void onCreate() {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    ArrayList<Person> person = (ArrayList<Person>) i.getParcelableExtra("personObject");

    //Get the Arraylist of Persons from MainActivity 
    listView.setAdapter(new personAdapter(this, R.layout.person_list_layout, person));
```

**EDIT:** stack error trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16698): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testApp/com.example.testApp.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at com.example.testApp.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(16698):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
```

**EDIT2:** Line 35 on error log

```
listView.setAdapter(new personAdapter(this, R.layout.person_list_layout, person));
```

Comment: What does Logcat show?

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testApp/com.example.testApp.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @user1281921: show more code from `SecondClass` class

Comment: Try changing your declaration to `ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();`

Comment: @hidro, tried changing this but still getting nullpointer exception error

Comment: @user1281921 post the entire stacktrace and the secondactivity class

Comment: @user1281921 what is line 35 in `SecondActivity.java`?

Comment: @user1281921 likely listview is null. check that

Comment: `listView.setAdapter(new personAdapter(this, R.layout.person_list_layout, person));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArrayList does not implements `Parcelable`, but it implements `Serializable`, so you can't use `getParcelableExtra` to receive the data, you must use `getSerializableExtra` instead.

```
ArrayList<Person> person = (ArrayList<Person>) i.getSerializableExtra("personObject");
```

Person class must implements `Serializable` too, here is the code example:

```
Person implements Serializable{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
   String id;
   String name;
}
```

**Update:**

Another solution: use `putParcelableArrayListExtra` and `getParcelableArrayListExtra`.

First activity:

```
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

public void onButtonClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("personObject", list);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Second Activity:

```
ArrayList<Person> person = (ArrayList<Person>) i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("personObject");
```

Note:  `Parcelable` is faster than `Serializable`, so the second solution is better if you want to pass a lot of data.

Comment: Using `Serializable` affects a lot to app performance when compare with `Parcelable`. I don't think using it is a good practice.

Comment: Thanks! the second solution worked but i didnt needed to cast (ArrayList<Person>)

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc Thanks for your comment, I will add your opinion in my answer, so it may help more people.

Answer (score 2):

You should use another function: `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)` [Google site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)) in main `Activity`, then `intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra` to get in second `Activity`.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

1.Create FirstActivity with one button

```
package com.appkart.sdcardconnection;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

                personList.add(new Person("10", "Arun"));
                personList.add(new Person("20", "Ankit"));          

                intent.putExtra("person_list", personList);
                startActivity(intent);              
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.appkart.sdcardconnection.FirstActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Activity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

3.Second Activity

```
package com.appkart.sdcardconnection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        List<Person> personList = (ArrayList<Person>) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra("person_list");

        for (Person person : personList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "id  : " + person.getId());
            Log.d(TAG, "name  : " + person.getName());

        }
    }
}
```

4.Person POJO

```
package com.appkart.sdcardconnection;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Person(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Use Serializable instead Parcelable. According to ArrayList java doc it implement Serializable. [Array list java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)