# Passing Arraylist data from one activity to other in OnPostExecute

Tags: android

I am trying to pass arraylist from one activity to other using Bundles in OnPostExecute method,i am not able to do so.I am not getting proper error also to typecast or do stuffs to remove error.I am not sure what is wrong here.

```
   ***here reminderList is List<GetReminder> reminderList;***

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                //Invoke webservice
                vaildUserId=WebService.invokeAuthenticateUserWS(loginUserName, loginPassword, "AuthenticateUser");
                if(vaildUserId>=0){
                    reminderList=WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS("GetReminder");
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArrayList("reminderList", reminderList);
                reminderIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReminderActivity.class));
                startActivity(reminderIntent);
            }
```

Comment: Can you post the log cat error output?

Comment: make`GetReminder` class as `Parceble` or `Serializable`  then pass with ` putSerializable()` method as your `reminderList` is not a String Array or List.

Comment: it shows putting StringArrayList can not be applied to bundle,i have tried using other options also with bundle but failed

Comment: @user370305 you should write this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you can use `putParcelableArrayListExtra()` and `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` methods which are defined in the `Intent` class.

1.Make sure your `GetReminder` class implements `Parcelable` .

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) is the document of `Parcelable` and it also contains a  typical implementation of `Parcelable`.

[Here](http://www.parcelabler.com/) is a website which can help you generate an Parcelable implementation of a class automotically.

2.In your `onPostExecute()` method put extra like this:

```
//Remember to declare reminderList as ArrayList here.
ArrayList<GetReminder> reminderList = ...;

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReminderActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("reminderList", reminderList);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your `ReminderActivity` class get the `ArrayList` like this:

```
ArrayList<GetReminder> list = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("reminderList");
```

BTW, there is also another way to solve your problem, you can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28733592/1297670).

Comment: getting putParcelableArrayListExtra cannot be applied to intent,one question just implementing parcealbe in GetReminder is enough?

Comment: @jenil Make sure the type of reminderList you passed to putParcelableArrayListExtra() is  declared as ArrayList. And yes,  just implementing parcealbe in GetReminder is enough. I'll change the code to show how to solve the problem you just met.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sampleapp/com.example.sampleapp.ReminderActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.example.sampleapp.GetReminder

Comment: I changed has you said now i am getting this

Comment: finally worked i followed has u posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733439/parceable-arraylist-of-objects/28733592#28733592 using serializable

Comment: @jenil You get that Exception because you didn't define GetReminder class as Parcelable correctly. To define a class as Parcelable, you need to add a CREATOR to it as well as implements those abstract methods. I update my answer so you can see how to do that at step 1.

Comment: yes i got it,but for now i am using your second approach.Can you please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084207/parsing-webservice-anytype-response

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `List<GetReminder> reminderList;` is not a String List.

To pass Custom Object List you have to make your Custom class either `Serializable` or `Parcelable`. In your case make `GetReminder` as `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

Then use `putExtra()` or `putSerializable()` of Intent to pass Serializable object.

Also some supercilious code I noted from your `onPostExecute()` as you have written

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReminderActivity.class));
startActivity(reminderIntent);
```

will cause creating two activity instance.

so remove first one,

`startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReminderActivity.class));`

Comment: For reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747727/pass-arraylist-of-user-defined-objects-to-intent-android and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: :) yes i added by mistake thanks for noting.  let me try out using parceable