# Receive ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, multidimensional-array

The question has been asked here [Pass multidimensional ArrayList of LatLng through intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744111/pass-multidimensional-arraylist-of-latlng-through-intent) but it does not have an actual answer.

I have done what the answer there states, and I can pass it through without error,

```
intent.putExtra("lat_lng_list", mLatLonList);
```

but I am unable to receive it on the other end. The closest I have come was using:

```
final ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> latLngList = intent.getParcelableExtra("lat_lng_list");
```

but this just returns null, even though it's not. I know LatLng implements parcelable, I was able to pass an ArrayList of LatLng using the same .putExtra and retrieving it with intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(), but that won't work for the multidimensional one either. Anything helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417241/passing-an-arraylistobject-from-one-intent-to-another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArrayList` does not implements `Parcelable`, but it implements `Serializable`. You can't use `getParcelableExtra` to receive the data, you must use `getSerializableExtra` instead. Like this:

```
final ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> latLngList = (ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>) intent.getSerializableExtra("lat_lng_list");
```

You can also use `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()` and `intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra()` if you use large `ArrayList`'s. Also make sure that `LatLng` implements `Serializable`.

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28733592/5457878

Comment: Wow, I had tried using that before but got an error, didn't even think about type casting! Thanks so much!